# How to correctly update the cell based on a condition?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I ran into troubles trying to make my script work and was wondering if anyone could help me figure it out.

I am working on a simple script in Google Sheets which would overwrite a D column cell in one row if columns A, B, C, E and F are the same for both rows. The screenshot of the example sheet can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzyCN.png). Row 2 is made based on the original reservation, where columns A-F are filled by an external program and columns G and H are later filled by Appsheet. If the reservation status changes, the external program will create a new row with columns A-F with updated reservation status. My idea is to have a script which would replace a cell in the D column of original reservation if it finds another row in data which has the same driver name, car, event, date and duration.

I have tried to base my script on duplicate delete script, but as an output, it deletes the "updated" row without replacing the D cell in the original. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```js
//overwrite old rows with updated rows
function update() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var update = false;
    for(j in newData){

      if(row.slice(0,2).join() == newData[j].slice(0,2).join() && row.slice(4,5).join() == newData[j].slice(4,5).join() && row.slice(3).join() !== newData[j].slice(3).join() ){
        update = true;
      }
    }
    if(!update){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }


  // Clear the existing info and update with newData.
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

- You want to compare columns A, B, C, E, F from the different rows.
- If all these values match, and values in D don't, you want to copy the value of column D from the row with higher index to the one with lower index and remove the row with higher index.
- You have date and time values in columns E and F.

If all these are correct, you can try this:

```
function update() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rowsToDelete = []; // Array to store the rows to be deleted (this avoids the deletion of rows messing with the loop indexes)
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var firstRow = data[i];
    for (var j = i; j < data.length; j++) {
      var secondRow = data[j];
      if (i != j && firstRow[0] == secondRow[0] && firstRow[1] == secondRow[1] && firstRow[2] == secondRow[2] && firstRow[4].getTime() == secondRow[4].getTime() && firstRow[5].getTime() == secondRow[5].getTime() && firstRow[3].toLowerCase() != secondRow[3].toLowerCase()) {
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue(secondRow[3]); // Copying value D from higher to lower index
        rowsToDelete.push(j + 1); // New row to be removed
      }
    }
  }
  rowsToDelete.sort(function(a, b){return b - a}); // Sorting the rows to delete from higher to lower (to avoid messing with loop indexes)
  for (var r = 0; r < rowsToDelete.length; r++) {
    sheet.deleteRow(rowsToDelete[r]); // Deleting rows
  }
}
```

You can check the inline comments to know what the code is doing, step by step.

Please note that, to compare values in columns E and F, you should use [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) or [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) (otherwise these conditions will return `false`).

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I am afraid I have not specified my question correctly. In the example, I used 2 rows, whereas, in reality, I have about 100 for different orders. That means I would need the script to go over the entire dataset to find existing rows which correspond to the conditions, instead of actually replacing D2 with D3, D4 with D5 and so on.

Comment: @EgorP I updated my answer based on your comment and your question edition. Please tell me if that works for you.